# IOS XCode correct place to put video file

Tags: ios, xcode

I place my homepage background with a infinity looping video. But as the title say I don't know where is the proper way to put the video file inside the project. For image I need to place it in assetCatalog else the app will be reject by apple. But I don't think assetCatalog is the place for video.

Anyone having experience with this problem? Thank for any advanced.

Comment: You can put video in a Group it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your video files in Assets.xcassets.

Assets.xcassets can be used to keep any media files like images and videos.

you can use this function to loop your video

```
func loopVideo(videoPlayer: AVPlayer) {

   NotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in

           videoPlayer.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
           videoPlayer.play()
        }
   }
```